# How to sum of values in multiple featureclasses?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, oracle10g, arcgis

I have cobbled together the code below that loops through some featureclasses and outputs the total by fc and also a sum of the number of feature classes. The final piece to my puzzle that I cant get right is how to now sum the totals of each feature class so I dont need to add them up in my head. I have read numerous similar posts but they all seem to be focused on returning the sum of a feature class, not sum of multiple feature classes. (Im on Win 7, Oracle 10g, Python 2.7.5, ArcGIS 10.2.1)
My working code so far .....

```
    FCS = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    FCS.sort()
    for fc in FCS:
            if fc.startswith("Book"):
                    DM1 = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
                    print "\t" + fc +" Record Count = "+  str(DM1)
                    # total = sum(str(DM1)) ####  my effort to return sum
                    # print "Book_** Record Count = " +total
    # and the number of feature classes (In case there were hundreds)
    fcCount = len(FCS)
    print '\n' '\t' "FeatureClasses found = " + str(fcCount)
```

Produces this result ....

```
15_Books_Base_count.py starts here......

Book_10 Record Count = 841
Book_20 Record Count = 209
Book_30 Record Count = 56
Book_40 Record Count = 32182
Book_50 Record Count = 40178
Book_60 Record Count = 8562
Book_70 Record Count = 2118
Book_80 Record Count = 6413
Book_90 Record Count = 645

FeatureClasses found = 11
```

I am after a returned line that has "Book_** Record Count = 91204".

Comment: What does this have to do with Oracle10g? there's no SQL or PL/SQL involved in your code.

Comment: You cant see the complete script (700 lines). The sql bit is not the prob.

Comment: Then why tag it as Oracle10g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable called `total`. Each time through the loop, increment `total` by the count of that feature class, `DM1`. Then print `str(total)` after the loop. Behold:

```
total = 0
FCS = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
FCS.sort()
for fc in FCS:
        if fc.startswith("Book"):                    
                getCountResult = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
                DM1 = int(getCountResult.getOutput(0))
                print "\t" + fc +" Record Count = "+  str(DM1)
                total += DM1
print "Book_** Record Count = " + str(total)
# and the number of feature classes (In case there were hundreds)
fcCount = len(FCS)
print '\n' '\t' "FeatureClasses found = " + str(fcCount)
```

Comment: That looks good thanks @Gary-s and an option I hadnt contemplated. I will have a go tomorrow morning when I return to work and advise.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try it?

Comment: Unfortunately only just now due to some urgent work. If I run the code I get the following error. "unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'Result'".  I tried adding 'int' in various places but still received unsupported oparand errors. With my limited knowledge, I doubt it has to do with field types as the count is of fc records, rather than field values. I searched further just now but have not come across any beter knowledge. If you run the code on  a sample set at your end, do you get the unsupported error feedback??

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1 and it works fine. But I see from the [Get Count documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-count.htm) that it returns a Result object, not an int, so you're supposed to call `getOutput(0)` to get the actual count. I don't know why that wasn't necessary in 10.3.1, but I suspect this will fix your issue.

Comment: I have tested in ArcGIS 10.2 and it works just fine. I havent moved to 10.3 yet but Im sure it will be fine with that version too thank you.